# How do I handle my json writes to update existing objects in ReactiveMongo?

Tags: json, scala, playframework-2.1, securesocial, reactivemongo

In my current Play2 project I have implemented ReactiveMongo to store my user objects.

**User:**

```
case class User(override var _id: Option[BSONObjectID] = None,
                override var created: Option[DateTime] = None,
                override var updated: Option[DateTime] = None,
                firstName: String,
                lastName: String,
                email: String,
                emailValidated: Boolean,
                phoneNumber: String,
                lastLogin: DateTime,
                linkedProviders: Seq[LinkedProvider],
                userRoles: Seq[UserRole.UserRole]) extends TemporalModel {
}

import EnumUtils.enumReads
implicit val userRoleReads = enumReads(UserRole)
import mongo_models.LinkedProvider.linkedProviderReads
implicit val userReads: Reads[User] = (
    (__ \ "_id").read[Option[BSONObjectID]] and
      (__ \ "created").read[Option[DateTime]] and
      (__ \ "updated").read[Option[DateTime]] and
      (__ \ "firstName").read[String] and
      (__ \ "lastName").read[String] and
      (__ \ "email").read[String] and
      (__ \ "emailValidated").read[Boolean] and
      (__ \ "phoneNumber").read[String] and
      (__ \ "lastLogin").read[DateTime] and
      (__ \ "linkedProviders").read(list[LinkedProvider](linkedProviderReads)) and
      (__ \ "userRoles").read(list[UserRole.UserRole])
    )(User.apply _)


  import EnumUtils.enumWrites
  import mongo_models.LinkedProvider.linkedProviderWrites
  import play.api.libs.json.Writes._

  implicit val userWrites: Writes[User] = (
    (__ \ "_id").write[Option[BSONObjectID]] and
      (__ \ "created").write[Option[DateTime]] and
      (__ \ "updated").write[Option[DateTime]] and
      (__ \ "firstName").write[String] and
      (__ \ "lastName").write[String] and
      (__ \ "email").write[String] and
      (__ \ "emailValidated").write[Boolean] and
      (__ \ "phoneNumber").write[String] and
      (__ \ "lastLogin").write[DateTime] and
      (__ \ "linkedProviders").write(Writes.traversableWrites[LinkedProvider](linkedProviderWrites)) and
      (__ \ "userRoles").write(Writes.traversableWrites[UserRole.UserRole])
    )(unlift(User.unapply))
```

**LinkedProvider:**

```
case class LinkedProvider(userId: String,
                          providerId: String,
                          authMethod: String,
                          avatarUrl: String,
                          oAuth1Info: Option[OAuth1Info] = None,
                          oAuth2Info: Option[OAuth2Info] = None,
                          passwordInfo: Option[PasswordInfo] = None) {

}

object LinkedProvider {

  implicit val o1 = Json.format[OAuth1Info]
  implicit val o2 = Json.format[OAuth2Info]
  implicit val p = Json.format[PasswordInfo]

  implicit val linkedProviderReads: Reads[LinkedProvider] = (
    (__ \ "userId").read[String] and
      (__ \ "providerId").read[String] and
      (__ \ "authMethod").read[String] and
      (__ \ "avatarUrl").read[String] and
        (__ \ "oAuth1Info").read[Option[OAuth1Info]] and
        (__ \ "oAuth2Info").read[Option[OAuth2Info]] and
          (__ \ "passwordInfo").read[Option[PasswordInfo]]
    )(LinkedProvider.apply _)

  implicit val linkedProviderWrites: Writes[LinkedProvider] = (
    (__ \ "userId").write[String] and
      (__ \ "providerId").write[String] and
      (__ \ "authMethod").write[String] and
      (__ \ "avatarUrl").write[String] and
      (__ \ "oAuth1Info").write[Option[OAuth1Info]] and
      (__ \ "oAuth2Info").write[Option[OAuth2Info]] and
      (__ \ "passwordInfo").write[Option[PasswordInfo]]
    )(unlift(LinkedProvider.unapply))
}
```

As you can see I have implemented reads and writes so that the objects are correctly stored
in the mongoDB instance.
When doing the insert with a new object everything is working like a charm and the object structure is correctly saved and retrieved from mongoDB.

What I'm having issues with is figuring out how to handle the updates.
So let say I want to update some values on my user object like this:

```
val userForUpdate = user.copy(
       firstName = identity.firstName,
       lastName = identity.lastName,
       email = identity.email.getOrElse(""),
       lastLogin = DateTime.now()
       )
```

And then call my update method:

```
UserDAO.update(user._id.get.stringify, userForUpdate, false)
```

**updateMethod:**

```
def update(id: String, document: T, upsert: Boolean)(implicit writer: Writes[T]): Future[Either[ServiceException, T]] = {
    document.updated = Some(new DateTime())
    Logger.debug(s"Updating document: [collection=$collectionName, id=$id, document=$document]")
    Recover(collection.update(DBQueryBuilder.id(id), DBQueryBuilder.set(document))) {
      document
    }
  }
```

**DBQueryBuilder.set() method:**

```
def set[T](data: T)(implicit writer: Writes[T]): JsObject = Json.obj("$set" -> data)
```

This will cause this error:

```
[error] application - DB operation failed: [message=DatabaseException['Mod on _id not allowed' (code = 10148)]]
[error] application - DatabaseException: [code=10148, isNotAPrimaryError=false]
```

since the writes, `(__ \ "_id").write[Option[BSONObjectID]]`, states that also the **_id** field should be serialized when calling the **DBQueryBuilder.set() method**. Updating **_id** is as we know not allowed and should definitely not be done in this case.

So my question is: How should I handle this? I guess there some smart Scala way that do not involve me writing the entire **"$set" -> query**? Maybe creating a better DBQueryBuilder? Maybe defining another writes definition?
Please gimmie your best shot and remember that I'm a Scala newbie so be gentle =) !

Comment: is the use of reactive mongo required? otherwise you may have a look at [play-salat](https://github.com/leon/play-salat), a ORM for the officialy supported casbah mongodb driver. it think it comes with all the stuff you need, without the need of writing writes & reads.

Comment: Hello! Thank you for your answer. Yes the use of ReactiveMongo is required.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
def set[T](data: T)(implicit writer: Writes[T]): JsObject = Json.obj("$set" -> data)
```

You could use something like that

```
def set[T](data: T)(implicit writer: Writes[T]): JsObject = {
    val data = Json.obj(data)
    val dataWithoutId = data.remove("_id")
    Json.obj("$set" -> dataWithoutId)
}
```

There should be something in the Play Json library to remove the `_id` field (but it may not be "remove(...)"...)

---

Since you use option you would probably write something like:

```
val userForUpdate = user.copy(
       id = None,
       firstName = identity.firstName,
       lastName = identity.lastName,
       email = identity.email.getOrElse(""),
       lastLogin = DateTime.now()
       )
```

---

The best way is probably to use a common trait for all classes representing Mongo documents (maybe the T you use?) and add on the trait the possibility to remove the id (set it to none).

This way you could call:

```
def set[T](data: T)(implicit writer: Writes[T]): JsObject = Json.obj("$set" -> data.copy(_id = None))
```

Comment: Hi there! Thank you for your answer! Setting the _id field to None won't work since the id field will still exist in the updated query. But your way of removing the field could work. Check out my answer, It's a bit explicit and can be shortened, what do you think?

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
def set[T](data: T)(implicit writer: Writes[T]): JsObject = {
    val jsonTransformer = (__ \ '$set \ '_id).json.prune
    val dataWithId = Json.obj("$set" -> data)
    val withoutId = dataWithId.transform(jsonTransformer).get
    withoutId
}
```

Comment: this seems nice, prune seems the way to do "remove()" of my answer